# INSERT INTO sql server error : invalid object name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_VIDEOS (
  TBL_VIDEOS.ID,
  TBL_VIDEOS.TITLE,
  TBL_VIDEOS.V_DESCRIPTION,
  TBL_VIDEOS.UPLOAD_DATE,
  TBL_VIDEOS.V_VIEWS,
  TBL_VIDEOS.USERNAME,
  TBL_VIDEOS.RATING,
  TBL_VIDEOS.V_SOURCE,
  TBL_VIDEOS.FLAG
) 
VALUES 
('Z8MTRH3LmTVm',
'Why Creativity is the New Economy',
'Dr Richard Florida, one of the world&#39;s leading ...
    this stuff does not matter, it is just wasted space',
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
0,
1,
0,
'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPX7gowr2vE&feature=g-all-u'
,0)
```

But I get this error message:

> Invalid object name 'TBL_VIDEOS'

Comment: You need to escape special or reserved characters.

Comment: In addition to fixing the table prefix inside the column list, and the single quote, did you try `dbo.TBL_VIDEOS`?

Comment: And are you sure you're in the right database? Do you get the same error with `SELECT ID FROM TBL_VIDEOS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the single quote in the description : "one of the world's leading experts"

I do not think the fact that the name of the table is an issue in this case but they are redundant.

The below will work:

```
create table TBL_VIDEOS (
ID nvarchar(100), TITLE nvarchar(100), V_DESCRIPTION nvarchar(2000), UPLOAD_DATE nvarchar(100), V_VIEWS nvarchar(100), USERNAME nvarchar(100), RATING nvarchar(100), V_SOURCE nvarchar(100), FLAG nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO TBL_VIDEOS ( 

 TBL_VIDEOS.ID, TBL_VIDEOS.TITLE, TBL_VIDEOS.V_DESCRIPTION, TBL_VIDEOS.UPLOAD_DATE, TBL_VIDEOS.V_VIEWS, TBL_VIDEOS.USERNAME, TBL_VIDEOS.RATING, TBL_VIDEOS.V_SOURCE, TBL_VIDEOS.FLAG) 

VALUES 

('Z8MTRH3LmTVm', 'Why Creativity is the New Economy', 'Dr Richard Florida, one of the world' + CHAR(39) + 's leading experts on economic competitiveness, demographic trends and cultural and technological innovation shows how developing the full human and creative capabilities of each individual, combined with institutional supports such as commercial innovation and new industry, will put us back on the path to economic and social prosperity.

Listen to the podcast of the full event including audience Q&A: http://www.thersa.org/events/audio-and-past-events/2012/why-creativity-is-the-new-economy

Our events are made possible with the support of our Fellowship. Support us by donating or applying to become a Fellow.

Donate: http://www.thersa.org/support-the-rsa Become a Fellow: http://www.thersa.org/fellowship/apply', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0, 1, 0, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPX7gowr2vE&feature=g-all-u' ,0)
```

Comment: @CodingBiz (I cannot comment your answer, I am too new): removing the name of the columns would be better practice but this is not the issue. I do believe it is due to the fact he was not escaping or rather replacing the single quote with it's ASCII equivalent.

Comment: I cant change it here, but I did escape it with HTML encoding.. the qoute represent in my database dtatement as &#39;

Comment: Try to recode by removing the table name from the list of columns (no need to schema sign), align each on its own line (this allows you to count). The other method to insert is to use a select statement. Highlighting the select statement only allows you to execute it and make sure that this returns a proper result set, with the right number of columns.

Comment: You may also want to schema sign your table name. I have seen people creating a table under their own user name schema and the engine will first try to insert into this table instead of the proper table. I would guess that dbo.TBL_VIDEOS would be your schema signed table name. You really need to include the schema ALL THE TIME. This also helps IntelliSense greatly.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `TBL_VIDEOS` from this portion

```
INSERT INTO TBL_VIDEOS (
  TBL_VIDEOS.ID,
  TBL_VIDEOS.TITLE,
  TBL_VIDEOS.V_DESCRIPTION,
  TBL_VIDEOS.UPLOAD_DATE,
  TBL_VIDEOS.V_VIEWS,
  TBL_VIDEOS.USERNAME,
  TBL_VIDEOS.RATING,
  TBL_VIDEOS.V_SOURCE,
  TBL_VIDEOS.FLAG
)
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO TBL_VIDEOS (
  ID,
  TITLE,
  V_DESCRIPTION,
  UPLOAD_DATE,
  V_VIEWS,
  USERNAME,
  RATING,
  V_SOURCE,
  FLAG
  )
```

And you can look into this, any where you have content like `world's leading experts` should be changed to `world''s leading experts`. By doing single quote twice, you are escaping the single quote

Comment: still error .. btw , I dont have qoute on my text "world leading exprrts"

Comment: have you tried what @AaronBertrand said in the comment? Also verify the spelling of your table name. Sometimes we think we have `VIDEO` but it was `VEDIO`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added: 
USE Name_Of_Your_Database

Answer (score 1):

In my case SQL Server does not like using single quotes for the COLUMNS portion, and it doesn't like using double quotes for the VALUES portion.

**WRONG**

```
INSERT INTO [sample].[dbo].[users]
('username', 'password')
VALUES('hello', 'hello')

INSERT INTO [sample].[dbo].[users]
("username", "password")
VALUES("hello", "world")
```

**CORRECT**

```
INSERT INTO [sample].[dbo].[users]
("username", "password")
VALUES('hello', 'world')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a hard refresh Ctrl+Shift+R

You may have had to allow SSMS to recognize a table after having just created it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case SQL gave the 'invalid object name' error message while trying to insert values using the below statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName] 
WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE col1 = val1)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [SchemaName].[TableName] (col1, col2,col3) 
  Values(val1, val2, val3)
END
```

To avoid this error I used the below statement to insert the record into the table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName] 
WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE col1 = val1)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO SchemaName.TableName (col1, col2,col3) 
   Values(val1, val2, val3)
END
```